# The value get by delegate method is been clear?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In tableViewControllerA.h I declare a delegate ,and in tableViewControllerA.m I implement the method when click a cell of the tableView, A will pass the value to B, and execute the perfromSegueWithIdentifier to jump to tableViewControllB,in tableViewControllB.m the getting method is called, and I get the value, but after the viewDidLoad() method call, the value become nil. Please help me to solve the problem.By the way , the property of the value is strong,nonatomic.

```html
DTZHomeTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "PassData.h"
@protocol PassDataDelegate 

-(void)passData:(PassData*) dataToProgram;

@end

@interface DTZHomeTableViewController : 

UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property(assign,nonatomic) id<PassDataDelegate> dataDelegate;

@end

PassData is an user-defined class



DTZHomeTableViewController.m
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

   ProgramTableViewController *programViewController=

[[ProgramTableViewController alloc]init];
 
   self.dataDelegate=programViewController;;
   
    
    PassData *jump=[[PassData alloc]init];
    jump.livingStatus=YES;
    jump.role=0;
    jump.index=indexPath.row;
    jump.curOnlineNum=305605;

   [self.dataDelegate passData:jump];

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSelectedProgram" sender:self];

}

ProgramTableViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DTZHomeTableViewController.h"

@interface ProgramTableViewController : 
UITableViewController<PassDataDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic) PassData * dataFromHome;

@end


 ProgramTableViewController.m

@implementation ProgramTableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"view did load%@",self.dataFromHome); // log :null
}
- (void) passData:(PassData *)dataToProgram
{
    
    self.dataFromHome=dataToProgram;
   
}
@end
```

Comment: You should post code showing how your delegate is set, passed, and used.

Comment: did you assign delegate = self

Comment: Did you try the approach I suggested in my answer?  Did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegation isn't the proper way to pass data to a segued view controller.  Instead, you want to pass the data in `prepareForSegue:sender:`

Remove the protocol and delegate.

Add properties to your ProgramTableViewController for the data you want to pass.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL livingStatus;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger role;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger row;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger curOnlineNum;
```

In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, set the ProgramTableViewController's passed properties to the values associated with the selected row:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)__unused sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ProgramTableViewController *controller = (ProgramTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.livingStatus = YES;
        controller.role = 0;
        controller.row = indexPath.row;
        controller.curOnlineNum = 305605;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't allocate and init ProgramTableViewController in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  Your segue will instantiate the destination view controller for you.

You don't even need to have a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.  You can create a push segue from the tableViewCell to ProgramTableViewController, right within Storyboard.  Give the segue an identifier (such as "showDetail").  Then in prepareForSegue, you assign the values, as I explained.

When you tap on that row, the segue will create a ProgramTableViewController, set the parameters, and present it for you.

Comment: Oh yeah ! Thank you very much ! delegate really is not proper of segued design. I can pass data in the prepare function! Thank →_→

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :)  Don't forget to accept it (by clicking the check mark), to mark your question as answered!